# Sending grpc Requests without waiting for response?

Tags: architecture, grpc, grpc-python

I just want to invoke a grpc method and exit from the process, I don't need the response back to the client.

My use case is like.

AWS Lambda will invoke only invoke multiple grpc request and exit without waiting for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gRPC on-the-wire does not support fire-and-forget RPCs. The client is free to ignore the results and the server can respond immediately before actually processing the request.

Comment: FWIW, fire-and-forget RPCs in other systems are quite possibly implemented as the client ignoring the result and the server responding immediately. In such cases, the RPC latency between the client and server is still present as it would be in gRPC.